# Retrieving current location in android of API Level 19 to 22

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-api-java-client

I use the code below in my project to retrieve the current location of the user. However, this seems to work on my test devices of API Level 23, but does not work on my test devices of API levels 19 to 22. The request for a location will return null and therefor place me at coordinates 0,0..

How can i get correct coordinates for API levels 19 to 22?

```
package be.enventorslab.pingvalue;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import be.enventorslab.pingvalue.functions.Functions;

public class NearbyLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

        public static final String TAG = NearbyLocationActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        Bundle bundle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_map);

            setUpMapIfNeeded();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000)
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000)
                    .setSmallestDisplacement(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (Functions.Permissions.getFineLocation(this)) {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                handleNewLocation(location);
            }
        } else {
            this.bundle = bundle;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == Functions.Permissions.MY_PERMISSIONS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onConnected(bundle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```